# How to use ajax $.post() in a callback?

Tags: ajax, laravel, fullcalendar

I'm trying to use Ajax in a callback on 'eventDrop'

Here is the line of code I use:

```
$.post('{{ route('update_event_ajax') }}', data);
```

But when add it, the calendar no longer appears.

Here is my FullCalendar script:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#calendar-NcAT6P42').fullCalendar( //calendars options...
        ,"eventDrop":
        function(event) {
            $('#event_id').val(event.id);
            $('#event_title').val(event.title);
            $('#event_footnote').val(event.footnote);
            $('#event_id_team').val(event.id_team);
            $('#event_id_customer').val(event.id_customer);
            $('#event_title').val(event.title);
            $('#event_start_date').val(moment(event.start).format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss'));
            $('#event_end_date').val(moment(event.end).format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss'));
            var data = {
                _token: '{{ csrf_token() }}',
                event_id: $('#event_id').val(),
                event_title: $('#event_title').val(),
                event_start_date: $('#event_start_date').val(),
                event_end_date: $('#event_end_date').val(),
            };
            $.post('{{ route('update_event_ajax') }}', data);
        },
        "events": ...);
});
```

I've also tried with `$.ajax(...)` but got the same problem

I assume that my Ajax isn't at the right place ? But where should I place it ?

Thanks in advance

edit:
I'm using Laravel 5.0 and Laravel 5 Full Calendar Helper (https://github.com/maddhatter/laravel-fullcalendar)

Comment: What value does this emit to the JavaScript code and how does it fail?  That looks like a perfectly reasonable call to `$.post()`, provided this server-side template code emits a valid URL.  Or is that template not server-side but client-side?  In which case this could be a string quoting error, which would be immediately evident in the browser's development console.

Comment: Check the browser console, see if there is any error.

Comment: @David I think I understand where the problem comes from: `{{route(\'update_event_ajax\')}}`. As I write the callback in my controller, it seems that I can't use the blade syntaxe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Blade syntax can't be used in an external Javascript file.

I fixed my problem by adding this line in my view:

```js
window['ajax_event_url'] = "{{ route('update_event_ajax') }}";
```

And then use it this way:

```js
$.post(ajax_event_url, data);
```